# i am using controller extension to insert a new record into student__c custom object

Tags: apex

Using ProcessAdmission controller extension i am trying to read data entered on the vf page to insert a new record into Student__C custom object. but not getting data instead i received "**Null pointer exception**" at bold lines.

**Visualforce page:**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="New Student Admission">

            <apex:outputLabel id="inputtxta" value="First Name" for="StdFName"/>
            <apex:inputText id="StdFName" value="{!StdFName}"/>
            <apex:outputLabel id="inputtxtb" value="Last Name" for="StdLName"/>
            <apex:inputText id="StdLName" value="{!StdLName}"/>
            <apex:outputLabel id="inputtxtc" value="Father's Name " for="StdFatherName"/>
            <apex:inputText id="StdFatherName" value="{!StdFatherName}"/>
            <apex:outputLabel id="selectLista" value="Gender" for="StdGender"/>
            <apex:selectList id="StdGender" value="{!gendervalue}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Male" itemLabel="male" />
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Female" itemLabel="female"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="Transgender" itemLabel="TansGender"/>
            </apex:selectList>
    <apex:outputLabel id="buttonid" value="button" for="validate"/>
          <apex:commandButton id="validate" value="Submit" action="{!submit}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
```

**Apex class:**

```
 public class ProcessAdmission {

    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public Student__c std;
    public String StdFName{get; set;}
    public String StdLName{get; set;}

    public String StdFatherName{get; set;}
    public String gendervalue{get; set;}
  //  public list<student__c> dataRecords{get; set;}
    public Student__c datarecords;

   public ProcessAdmission(ApexPages.StandardController con)
    {
        /*dataRecords = [select id, Student_First_Name__c, student_Last_Name__c, father_Name__c, gender__C 
        from student__c
         WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];*/
        **datarecords = (Student__c)controller.getRecord();**

    }
       /* datarecords = (Student__c)controller.getRecord();     

    }*/


   /* public Student__C getStd()
    {
        return std;
    }*/
    public void submit()
    {
       /* std.Student_First_Name__c = stdFirstName;
        std.Student_Last_Name__c = stdlastName;
        std.Father_Name__c = stdfatherName;
        std.gender__c = gender;
*/
      /* StdFName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('StdFName');
        StdLName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('StdLName');
        StdFatherName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('StdFatherName');
        gendervalue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('gendervalue');*/
        **system.debug('the value is '+stdFname);**
        std.Student_First_Name__c = stdFName;
        std.Student_Last_Name__c = stdLName;
        std.Father_Name__c = stdfatherName;
        std.gender__c = gendervalue;
        student__C singleRec;   
        /*for(student__c std : dataRecords)
        {
            singleRec = 
        }*/
        insert dataRecords;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tough to say for sure where you're getting the error (there is no bold formatting in a block of code), but I'm guessing it's because you're referencing your `controller` variable in the constructor without ever setting it. Adding the following as the first line in your constructor should do the trick:

```
this.controller = con;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have get and set methods against string you do not need to do `getParameters().get('StdFName');` kind of stuff. getter method will get data from VF page anyways few things :

1) You can use the object and its field directly on the page without using string placeholders
2) you need to instantiate ("new") the object Student__c in constructor and then insert it. In your case you do not have an instance , so null pointer.

code can be simple like :

```
public student__c std {get;set;}

public constructor() {
    std = new student__c();
}

public void submit() {
    insert std
}
```

and on page

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!std.field__c}"/>
```